# Введение данных с помощью Scanner в java

Tags: java, ооп

Условие задания изменить класс Library так чтобы пользователь сам вводил значения параметров

```
    package pl.mystudy2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Books {
    String bookTitle;
    String bookAuthor;
    int bookYear;
        public Books(String a,String b,int c){
            bookTitle = a;
            bookAuthor =b;
            bookYear = c;
        }
}

package pl.mystudy2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Library {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);



        Books book1 = new Books("Lalka","BolesławPrus",2010);
        Books book2 = new Books("Krzyżacy","Henryk Sienkiewicz",2016);


        System.out.println("Książka: " + book1.bookTitle + ", " + book1.bookAuthor + ", " + book1.bookYear);
        System.out.println("Książka: " + book2.bookTitle + ", " + book2.bookAuthor + ", " + book2.bookYear);
    }
}
```

Пожалуйста помогите решить

Comment: о методах класса scanner читал?

Comment: ну да но не понимаю как это здесь реализовать

Comment: что именно вызывает вопросы?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы в Books book1 = new Books("Lalka","BolesławPrus",2010);  вместо пареметров в скобках я все вводил через сканер

Comment: ты можешь считывать параметры отдельно, (имя, название, год) и сохранять их в переменные, затем передать эти переменные в качестве параметров к конструктор

Comment: можеш на коком то примере показать что ты имеешь ввиду я что-то не могу понять

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    System.out.println("введи bookTitle");
    String bookTitle = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("введи bookTitle");
    String bookAuthor = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("введи bookYear");
    int bookYear = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());


    Books book1 = new Books(bookTitle,bookAuthor, bookYear);
```

Comment: Названия переменных указание в другом классе в классе Library нужно настроить вывод так чтобы имена переменных не повторялись

Comment: назови переменные как тебе надо

Comment: Спасибо помог))